# Stats for stock wheels on Btwin Triban 540

Tags: wheels, weight

I'd like to know the specs of the wheels that I currently have (weight specifically), which are present on every lower end BTwin road bike.

The only information decathlon seem to list for their website is that it's 32 spoke (https://www.decathlon.co.uk/triban-520-road-bike-sora-black-red-id_8322663.html):

```
WHEELS
B'TWIN Sport wheels, 32 spokes.
Aero 32 hub. Front and rear quick-release skewers.
```

Could anyone provide a link to a spec for the wheels, or more detailed information on weight?

Comment: If you don't see a marker on the wheels for what rim and hub is being run, chances are its an OEM only wheel with a generic hub. As for weight, use a scale. And weight is not nearly as big of a deal as people make it out to be for wheels. If you're in the tour de france or something, maybe. But for Joe Schmoe? Not so much.

Comment: Lower-spec bikes tend to reduce cost in the wheels more than other parts of the bike.  Likely any wheel will be better/lighter than the stock ones.  However heavier/cheaper wheels do tend to be stronger sheerly because of their higher mass.

Comment: Would love some feedback on the down vote, as far as I can tell this question fits within the rules of the forum?

Comment: @tompreston not me, but its heading slightly toward a "shopping" type question.  Or  part if it is "how much do my wheels weigh" which you could measure easier than any of us, using a scale with suitable range.  For a comparison with the review you want to weigh the wheels separately, without tyres or tubes, and without QR skewers or TAs or reflectors, and ideally take the cassette off too.    Or leave the cassette on and google for its weight, then subtract from your rear wheel measurement.

Comment: @Criggie fair point, and I accept that, but it would be good (as these wheels are used on the majority of the triban range) to get an answer on SE, I am perhaps not the only one googling this.  When I find time I'll invest in some scales and put up an answer.

Answer (score 3):

While it is likely they are solely an OEM rim, they look an awful lot like Mavic A119's which are spec'd without decals on a lot of entry road and endurance bikes as stock equipment.

Profile looks the same, they have eyelets, and the wear indicator groove, they also appear to be pinned at the seam as are the entry level A119. There is probably no way to know for sure but that would be my guess. If this is the case the rest of the specs can be found [here](https://shop.mavic.com/en-int/a-119-j24600.html#1028=3283&1035=3501&1039=3514)
[image]

You could take the tire off and measure the inner and outer widths as well as the side profile and whether or not they are double wall and compare. If it all matches my bet is they are Mavic A119s. Which is a decent beginner set but nothing amazing.